# How do I create a hyperlink from data in a string?

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, wsgi

I have a tuple which is being converted to a string and output in HTML. The string contains a link to a page (eg. http://www.google.com) but the link doesn't actually hyperlink to google.com because it's just seeing it as text.

Could anyone assist me in the way to solve this problem? This is my code:

```
commentString = ''
callComments = (interface.list_comments(db,10))
for comment in callComments:
    commentString += str(comment) + '<br> <br>'

content = {'comments': '<p>%s</p>' % commentString,
           }
```

HTML SIDE:

```
<div class = "comments">
<p>These are some comments:</p>
 %comments
</div>
```

Comment: use regex replace to autohyperlink it.

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, a hyperlink is created by the  tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp